# Connecting multiple MySQL tables with Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, insert-into

I have 3 different tables on MySQL:

- Clients
- Flights
- Bookings

On `Clients` I have

- Name
- Last Name
- ID
- Flight Number (from Flights table)
- Booking Number (from Bookings table)

On `Flights` I have

- ID (from Clients)
- Flight Number
- Company
- Date

On `Bookings` I have

- ID (from Clients)
- Booking Number
- Hotel
- Check-in date
- Check-out date

I want, after creating a Client, to make what I create on Flights and Bookings tables link on the Clients.

So, each Client has an ID that is also inserted into Flights and Bookings tables. And I need to link that Clients.ID row to it's row on Flights and Bookings.

Is this possible with Foreign Keys?

I tried making `Clients.ID` a Primary Key and `Flights.ID` and `Booking.ID` a Foreign Key, but then when I use `INSERT INTO` I get :

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

The SQL query was:

```
INSERT INTO clients (name, lastname, id) VALUES ('Jane', 'DOE', 123123123);
```

The SQL query to create the Foreign Keys was:

```
ALTER TABLE clients ADD CONSTRAINT fk_flightid FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES flights(id);` and 

ALTER TABLE clients ADD CONSTRAINT fk_bookingid FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES bookings(id);`
```

This is my first time coding MySQL, sorry if my explanation is messy.

Comment: Inserting into `Client` should not generate an error, as it is the parent table in both relationships. Maybe you created one (or both) relationship the other way around? Would you please edit your questiont to show the output of command `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for all three tables?

Comment: @GMB when I query `SHOW CREATE TABLE` I get `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

Comment: You need to add the table name at the end of the command, as [explained in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html) : `SHOW CREATE TABLE clients`.

Comment: @GMB I'll give it a go. In the meantime, I updated the question with the queries I used for the foreign keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  have created constraints that make `client` a child table of `flights` and `bookings`. As a consequence, you cannot create new clients (you would need to create parent records in the two other tables first).

In your database design, `client` should be the parent table, with `flights` and `bookings` as children tables.

Consider:

```
ALTER TABLE flights 
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_flights_client_id 
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES client(id);

ALTER TABLE bookings 
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_bookings_client_id 
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES client(id);
```

Other remarks:

- columns `Flight Number (from Flights table)` and `Booking Number (from Bookings table)` do not make sense in the `Client` table. These information belong to the children table, and can be accessed through `JOIN`s
- I would recommend renaming columns `ID` to `ClientID` in all 3 tables; using a name that makes sense functionaly is better than a generic name.

Comment: This solved it! I was creating the Foreign Keys on the parent table, and they should be created on the child tables. This is it right? Thank you!

Comment: @JoãodeSousa: welcome ! Yes this is exactly right. PS: please consider my other remarks as well, they should help further improve your schema.

Comment: I just saw your remarks! The `Flight Number` and `Booking Number` on the `Client` table were created so when I show the table on a HTML page I can link them to the values I can, now, connect throught the `ClientID`. So, should I do this throught `JOIN`?

Comment: Yes you do connect `flights` and `bookings` using `ClientID`, hence I don't see the need for columns `Flight Number` and `Booking Number` in `Client`.